# Flutter using ".withOpacity" leads to "the field is initialized with a non constant value"

Tags: flutter, dart, opacity

I have an own class for my app-colors:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
class AppColors {
  final objectRow=const Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withOpacity(0.5);

  const AppColors();

}
```

If I don't use `.withOpacity` the constructor can be const but if I use it I have to delete the `const`. I don't understand why... Please explain to me why the opacity can't be known at compile-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code above `const Color(0xFFFFFFFF)` is a constant, but `withOpacity(0.5)` creates a new `Color` value at runtime with a different opacity.

You don't need to call `withOpacity` to adjust the opacity of the color, since the first two hexadecimal digits in the color already refer to the opacity. You can achieve the desired result by adjusting those digits `const Color(0x80FFFFFF)`.